IHttpClientFactory always causes a timeout in the first request
We are using the IHttpClientFactory to connect to an external service using the following code:
// register service 
services.AddHttpClient("NoProxy")
        .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
                     {
                         return new HttpClientHandler
                         {
                             UseProxy = false,
                             Proxy = null
                         };
                     });
    
// g2g function
public async Task<CitizenResponse> GetResponseUsingFactory(CitizenReq request)
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
    var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    delegate (object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
         {
             return true; // Always accept
         };
    
    var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("NoProxy");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user_key", _apiKey);
    
    // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = _keep_alive;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", _connection);
    
    _logger.LogInformation($"API request : {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request)}");
    
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    
    response = await _retryPolicy.JustHttpRetry.ExecuteAsync(() =>
                        client.PostAsync($"{_g2gUrl}/api/validateCitizenData", data));
    
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation($"API response : {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response)}");
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CitizenResponse>(result,
                     new JsonSerializerSettings() { MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore })!;
    }
    else
    {
        //send email
        await FailedNotification();
        throw new Exception("G2G API is down");
    }
}

Each time the service runs, we get a connection timeout 408 error. If we did a second call, everything goes smoothly.

We have investigated and found out that the connection header is set to close. it seems that the tcp connection somehow ignore it .

We tried to set the idle-time out for the http connections in IIS to 1 min to avoid keeping the connection open but that doesn't seem to do anything.


Does anyone have any idea what we can investigate next?

dot core 8 @marc_s

Unrelated: microsoft advises against using interpolated strings in logging. But that is definitely not the cause of your problem. Do you have access to server logs?

I wonder if it is an expired cookie.  The cookie will get deleted after failing and then code will work next time.

@Fildor  Yes we have access to server logs . which loggs should i look for ? i don't have logs to the destination as it is an external entity .

@jdweng We dont set any cookies . How can we check that ? do you suspect of a cookie automaticlly set for example ?

search internet for "Window Check Cookies".  Usually cookies are established as part of an http connection.  You are failing first time and not second time so it sound like a cookie issue.

You may want to report issue to website.  It may be the website has code to stop service attacks but it also is creating you issue.  Issue like this can be fixed by deleting cookies before connecting.  Many sites require a two step authentication where step one is to get credentials and step two is to perform a query.  You may be skipping the credential step.  The cookie will get set during the credentials.  But then it wouldn't work 2nd time without credentials.  Are you using two steps?

Looking at your code you may need to add the HTTP Header "User Agent".  The User Agent is used to specify the type of Browser that is used for the connection.  The wrong browser setting may be causing issue.  Does issue happen if you use a browser instead of c# code?  Try Postman and see if that gives same issue.  Postman adds some HTTP headers automatically.  If Postman works check the Postman Control Panel which will give the complete http request including added headers.  Then add to your c# code the missing headers that postman adds.

you are also missing using on the response
